# Running PHP script on Perl or sh error. Not found

Tags: php, bash, perl, shell, cron

I'm currently running a cron job that loads a php script.
I keep getting an error, `sh 1 /usr/bin/php: not found.` 
I tried it two other ways but to no avail. 
on a perl script. I tried.

```
my $x = qx('/usr/bin/php /home/script.here');
```

This doesn't generate anything and sends me an error message on my mail. 
But if I run the line

```
/usr/bin/php /home/script.here
```

on my shell, it works.

I also create a script 1.sh and had this.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -v
```

I run the script `./1.sh` and it shows the result. But as soon as I try to call it via cron or `/bin/sh 1.sh`, it just fails and can't find the php path even if it was explicitly stated.

Am I missing anything?

I also tried this on php5, but same error.

Comment: Please fix your formatting, and even more importantly, tell us what error you got!

Comment: You need to start flagging questions as completed if there is a satisfactory answer. You keep asking questions yet you never mark them as completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally forgot about this question.
Found a solution.
I just added 
SHELL=/bin/bash in crontab and the scripts worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem are the single quotes inside the qx() operator. Remove them:

```
my $x = qx(/usr/bin/php /home/script.here);
```

As long as they are there the shell tries to find a command "`script.here`" in the directory "`/usr/bin/php /home`" (yes, with the space in the directory name).